# Inner product practice problem

Tags: linear-algebra

[image: Practice question for Final]

This is a practice question for the final exam but I'm not sure how to start it. Is it possible to multiply vector v and w into matrix A?

Comment: Vectors are matrices, and you can multiply matrices when their dimensions allow for it.

Answer (score 1):

You want to check the inner product properties, see here
[Inner Product Definition](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HermitianInnerProduct.html). Ill show you a few, then you can do the rest. Let $x,y,z\in \mathbb{C}^2$, $\alpha, \beta \in \mathbb{C}$:

(1) Linearity in first slot:
$$ \langle x+z , y \rangle  = (x+z) A (y)^* = xA(y*) +zAy^* = xAy^* + zAy^* = \langle x, y\rangle + \langle z, y\rangle $$ 
$$ \langle \alpha x, y\rangle =  \alpha x A y^* = \alpha (xAy^*) = \alpha \langle x,y\rangle$$

(2) Conjugate Symmetry:
$$\langle x,y \rangle  = x Ay^* = (yA^*x^*)^* = (y Ax^*)^* = \langle y ,x\rangle^*$$
Where I have used that the conjugate transpose of $A$ is $A$ itself, which you can check. You got it from here?

Regarding the conjugate issue in the comments:
$$A^* = \bar{A}^T = \overline{\begin{pmatrix}3 & i \\ -i & 2 \end{pmatrix}}^T = \begin{pmatrix}3 & -i \\ i & 2 \end{pmatrix}^T = \begin{pmatrix}
3 & i \\
-i & 2 
\end{pmatrix} = A$$

Comment: I'm not sure what the asterisk mean?

Comment: @anonymous9254 conjugate

Comment: So do you multiply (1+i)(3+i) and so forth then conjugate? or do you conjugate w and make it 3-i,1+2i then multiply with v?